# How to draw a black dashed line using RegionPlot?

Tags: plotting

I use Mathematica 11. I type the following code in Mathematica 11:

```
RegionPlot[0 <= y <= x && y <= 1, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

The output is:

[image: region plot]

Now I want to add a black dashed line from (1,0) to (1,1) on the above figure, what code should I input? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You can do this with the `Epilog` option to `RegionPlot`.

Comment: @BrettChampion Thank you for your comment. I have solved the  question.

Comment: Glad to hear it!